# Change a google map iframe src attribute using javascript on button click event

Tags: jquery, iframe, maps, src

I have a contact page with like 10 different addresses and a single google map iframe in the middle, i want to make the addresses clickable and when u click on a specific adress, the content of the map change and points to the clicked adress.

I'm a jquery newbie and i dont know ho to do this.

For now im stuck with this, but it's not working:

HTML:

This is the map loading by default with id "map".

```
<iframe id="map" width="650" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=it&amp;geocode=&amp;q=23,+Quai+des+Bergues&amp;aq=&amp;sll=46.198392,6.142296&amp;sspn=0.084955,0.222988&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Quai+des+Bergues+23,+Grottes+-+Saint-Gervais,+1201+Gen%C3%A8ve,+Svizzera&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=46.206419,6.145108&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near"></iframe>
```

This is the button with id "changesrc".

```
<input type="submit" name="changesrc" id="changesrc" value="Another Adress" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#changesrc').click(function() {
        $('#map').attr('src','http://maps.google.it/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=it&amp;geocode=&amp;q=roma&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.811729,12.738513&amp;sspn=2.927223,7.13562&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Roma,+Lazio&amp;t=m&amp;z=11&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed');
        });
    </script>
```

Any suggestion? Any help is very much appreciated. thanks!

---

I was able to make it work properly now! i set up the input to look like normal links so now it's all ok, but i have one problem:

When i click to change the map, the new map showing is not "centered" where the pin is, it's moved wrongly (the pin and central location are now in the top left corner).

I think this happens because of the "display: none" that is creating the issue. There's a way to fix that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the #changesrc exist more than once? Then you should use the `class` attribute instead of `id` because unlike the latter, the former is allowed to exist more than once.

You cannot access the `src` attribute because of your browser's security rules (cross domain access). This applies to all JavaScript, not only to jQuery and Google Maps.

But you can wrap all maps in a <div> tag and show it on demand. Of course all maps (except for possibly your default map) should be hidden at first via CSS.

You can see it all in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/FDKHee/pYX6Y/7 
(CSS is to the upper right)

Comment: Thank you! i was able to make it working pretty fast, you are awesome!

Comment: Just one more thing, is it possible to set the click on "a" element instead of "input" ? And... for the default map i set it to "display: inline" to show it by default also when not clicking on any button, but it gets some different margin in the bottom after i click on a second map, so the content below the map moves a little. Do you know why?

Comment: nevermind, i solved the margin issue! :). I just want to know if it's possible to use "a" element insted of "input", because i wish to use names of addresses instead of numbers for trigger the map change on click! thanks in advance!

Comment: Technically, a &lt;input&gt; tag is not allowed to have other tags inside. Instead, you can bind the click event to the container of each address.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/pYX6Y/9/ for a working example. Please consider accepting this answer (green checkmark icon)

Comment: Regarding your `pin not centered` problem: No, it can't be the `display: none`, because the iframe "doesn't notice" that is was hidden. Instead I suspect the size (height/width) of the map to be the problem. Does your design allow for larger maps? Also try re-pasting Google Maps' embed code. They save address and geo-coordinates separately.

Comment: i solved the issues by searching around the web, now the code is working perfeclty, i switched the display:none to visibility:hidden; position:absolute; and now the pin is perfectly centered! I also tweaked a bit the js to do it nicely. Im going to Accept your answer because you pointed me in the right direction and helped me so much! thank you! cheers.